# Current datetime in XML

Tags: odoo

I use python date time function without problem using XML time.strftime but it's impossible

```
<tree string="Mission" colors="blue:datetime_field > time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')">
```

Same problem with datetime.datetime.now() and DateTime.today()

Answer (score 0):

In `.xml` side `<, >, <=, >=` is not supported. So we need to use `&lt, $gt, &lt= and &gt=`

Try this, may be work for you,

```
<tree colors="blue:datetime_field &gt; current_date_time;" string="Mission">
   <!-- your field -->
</tree>
```